# Kendo UI Mobile - how do I do fixed-fluid-fixed clickable items in a listview?

Tags: kendo-ui

In my kendo mobile app I have some listviews that require more than one action.  I need something like what is show in the [Link Items & Detail Buttons demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/listview/detailbuttons.html) but more flexible.  In my case, I need to cover the following scenarios (all sections clickable):

```
[icon][text of the item]

[text of the item][icon]

[icon][text of the item][icon]
```

...where `[icon]` is some font icon.

I've started on a solution but before I go any further, I want some feedback to make sure I am not overlooking a better approach or something already built into Kendo.

Each "part" of the `<LI>` needs to perform a distinct action when clicked.  To handle this, I have a click binding on the `<UL>`.  I also have a `data-command-name` attribute on each element in the `<LI>` template so that I know what the user tapped/clicked.

**I have put together a fiddle but jsFiddle is reformatting the HTML part when it loads (I think because of the template script tags).  Once you load the fiddle please replace the HTML with the following to get it working:**

**HTML**

```
<div id="itemsView" data-role="view" data-model="vm">
  The red, silver and blue sections along with the X & Y are not part of the design, they are there just to make my intent more obvious.
  <ul data-role="listview" data-bind="source: items, click: clickHandler"
  data-template="itemsTemplate"></ul>

  <script id="itemsTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">

    <div class = "left-column" data-command-name="left (red)" > X </div>
    <div class="right-column" data-command-name="right (blue)">Y</div > 
    <div class = "content-column" data-command-name="content (silver)"> #=Name# </div>

  </script>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.left-column {
  float: left;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: red;
}
.content-column {
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: silver;
}
.right-column {
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var vm = kendo.observable({
  items: [{
    Selected: false,
    Name: "Item1"
  }, {
    Selected: false,
    Name: "Item2"
  }, {
    Selected: false,
    Name: "Item2"
  }],

  clickHandler: function (e) {
    var cmd = e.target.context.attributes["data-command-name"]
    if (cmd) {
      alert(cmd.value);
    }
  },
});

kendoApp = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {
  transition: "slide",
  platform: 'android'
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Kydw/

So to summarize my questions:

1) Is there a better/built-in way of doing this?

2) If not, any tips on the CSS?  For instance, why in Android is the height of the list items smaller than prior to my customization?

Comment: your jsFiddle comes up with all boxes blank for me.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike thanks for taking a look.  I just tried the fiddle in chrome (the browser I used to create it), and it works.  I also just tried it in firefox and ie and it works so I'm not sure what trouble you are encountering.  Of course, the result pane in all three cases is just black because the HTML is being reformatted by jsfiddle (see my comments about that in the question).  I'll add the CSS and JavaScript to the question.  The HTML is already there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think the strategy that you are using is completely fine and acceptable for Kendo UI Mobile.

2) Kendo UI Mobile applies some pretty specific styling in the way of `line-height` and a few other items that will affect how the list item is displayed if you then customize margin or padding with your own CSS.  I wouldn't worry too much about it though.